# How to make part of a bar plot transparent to unhide the filled region beneath it using matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, fill

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
CSP Min Max
A   107.0   111.0
B   126.0   156.0
```

`df.to_dict()` is as follows:

```
{'Min': {'A': 107.0, 'B': 126.0}, 'Max': {'A': 111.0, 'B': 156.0}}
```

I want to plot a bar plot for A and B by hiding the part between 0 and Min, and only showing the part between Min and Max. Therefore, I chose to color the Min as white color. The code looks as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 8))

df.plot(kind = "bar",
        stacked = True, color = ["white", "orange"],
        ax = ax)

plt.legend([])
```

And the resulting plot is as shown:
[image]

I also want to plot a colored range between 55 and 148. So I used `plt.fill_between()` for this purpose.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 8))

ax.fill_between(x = [-1, 2],
                y1 = [55, 55],
                y2 = [148, 148],
                color = "gray",
                alpha = 0.15,
                )

plt.legend([])
```

It looks as follows:
[image]

Now I want to combine these two into one single plot. I used the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 8))

df.plot(kind = "bar",
        stacked = True, color = ["white", "orange"],
        ax = ax)

ax.fill_between(x = [-1, 2],
                y1 = [55, 55],
                y2 = [148, 148],
                color = "gray",
                alpha = 0.15,
                )

plt.legend([])
```

The resulting plot is as shown:
[image]

The problem is that the white bar is overlapping the gray region which it should not. So, how can I make the bottom part of the bar transparent so that the gray region beneath it is still visible?

Comment: You can set the white color by using RGBA string as `#ffffff00`.

Comment: Thank you! That did the job. But could you explain why using the RBGA string worked but not using "white" as a color?

Comment: With RGBA string, the last item is alpha, which controls the color opacity. Setting it to `0` means transparency, while with normal color string such as "white", its alpha is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just plot (no stack) `df['Max']` with `bottom` option using `df['Min']`:

```py
df['Max'].plot(kind = "bar",
               color="orange",
               ax = ax,
               bottom=df['Min'])
```